# Swift SK game works correctly in simulator, labels missing in physical iPhone 5S (both iOS8)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm writing a game using sprite kit, first time so mistakes are inevitable :)

So running it in the simulator when certain events happen it's quite laggy (fps drops to 11 or less).

So I decided to see what happens on a real iPhone 5S.

Things run a little better: still lags at those events but not as badly.

However quite a few of my labels are missing: they appear fine in the Simulator but are completely missing in the physical device (just empty space where they should be).

Running ios8 in the simulator (5S) and on the 5S, code written in Swift.

Any hints at what I should look at?

Comment: Might be a silly question but this was the iPhone 5S simulator in which they showed up?

Comment: Because the simulator supports less features than your iPhone it's  probably because your game uses a feature that makes the labels invisible or hidden. Of course it could be a beta issue as well... First thing to try: remove everything but the labels

Comment: @holex Swift is **definitely** not 'a concept only', an implementation exists. Not sure what help you think you were giving in telling me it's not ready for commercial development nor why you signed off with 'you are welcome': for what exactly?

Comment: @holex It's not just a concept. This is not the same as saying it is not ready for commercial development, which I agree with. You are very, very welcome.

Comment: @holex The problem with your statement is nothing to do with Swift. You seemingly have no idea what the word 'concept' means. So let me help you out:

**concept**
ˈkɒnsɛpt
noun
_an abstract idea._

Swift is not an abstract idea: it exists as a concrete implementation.

You are very welcome.

Comment: @holex: I "don't have any point you are capable of understanding". FTFY. Muppet.

Comment: @holex: It is so interesting that you keep confirming that you are far down the bell curve of intelligence.

Comment: @holex: "you have already been educated how to ask a simple question" LOL your command of English is as good as your command of Swift. You should sign up for a local English language class. Literally none of your comments qualify as an answer anymore than the random patterns made by a monkey with severe diarrhoea would make the works of shakespeare.
You are very welcome.

Comment: @holex blah, blah, blah. An empty vessel making a lot of noise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you should try to isolate the problem. Try and see if the labels are indeed hidden or if they are behind a view. Download a hierarchy viewer such as Reveal App and try and find the UILabels. If they exist in both, the hierarchy viewer and the Simulator but not the physical iOS device, try and upload it to a different device. If it happens on the other device too, something is wrong with your code. We cant help unless we have something to work with.